# remove straight line and set label/title to month name instead number using ggplot + gganimate

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I have geom_line plot (using airquality data for reproducible example) showing temperature changes, a line per month, and then gganimate this way:

```
library("tidyverse")
library("gganimate")
data("airquality")

ggplot(airquality, aes(Day, Temp, color = Month)) +
     geom_line(size = 2) +
     geom_dl(aes(label = Month), method = list(dl.trans(x = x + 0.1, y = y + 0.25), "last.points", fontface = "bold")) +
     transition_time(Month) +
     labs(title = 'Month is {frame_time}') +
     shadow_mark(aes(color = Month),size=1, alpha=0.7, past=T, future=F) +
     geom_path(aes(color = Month), size = 1)
```

Rendering this animation:

[image]

My main issue is to achieve the same but **showing Month names instead of numbers (allowing me to puth Month Name in label and Title)** and **get rid of the straight line that connected beginning and ending of every line**.
I've tried this (no success so far):

```
aq <- airquality %>%
      dplyr::mutate(Month = month.name[Month])

ggplot(aq, aes(Day, Temp, color = Month)) +
  geom_line( size = 1) +
  geom_dl(aes(label = Month), method = list(dl.trans(x = x + 0.1, y = y + 0.25), "last.points", fontface = "bold")) +
  transition_time(Month) +
  labs(title = month.name['{frame_time}']) +
  shadow_mark(size = 1, colour = 'grey') +
  geom_path(aes(group = Month), size = 1)

Error: time data must either be integer, numeric, POSIXct, Date, difftime, orhms
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(cl[cl != 0]) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In min(cl[cl != 0]) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In min(cl[cl != 0]) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your month name as a new variable, and use that for the `label`. Then you can use `transition_states` instead of `transition_time`, which takes only numeric, integer, or date/time. You could set a full date column and use that in `transition_time`, but using `transition_states` is pretty easy. You'll need to order your levels if you go this route, otherwise it'll order them alphabetically as `states`.

```
library("tidyverse")
library("gganimate") # devtools::install_github("thomasp85/gganimate")
library("directlabels")
library("transformr") # devtools::install_github("thomasp85/transformr")
data("airquality")

aq <- airquality %>%
  dplyr::mutate(MonthName = month.name[Month])

aq$MonthName <- factor(aq$MonthName, levels = c("May", "June", "July", "August", "September"))

ggplot(aq, aes(Day, Temp, color = Month)) +
  geom_line( size = 1) +
  geom_dl(aes(label = MonthName), method = list(dl.trans(x = x + 0.1, y = y + 0.25), "last.points", fontface = "bold")) +
  transition_states(MonthName, transition_length = 3, state_length = 1) +
  labs(title = 'Month is {closest_state}') +
  shadow_mark(size = 1, colour = 'grey') +
  geom_path(aes(group = MonthName), size = 1)
```

[image]